# How can i create row of images with specific space between them

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i create row of images with specific space between them, when i use wrap the direction didn't working my images are in vertical order as default

my wrap property of direction is not in the default manner it's showing in vertical, and if i note it to show in horizontal it's still showing in vertical.. whya do i do..?

Comment: can you share image of what you want to get?

Comment: you can use `Row` widget and set `mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`

Comment: that doesn't working... and even wrap with direction horizontal doesn't working

Comment: can you share a picture of what you are getting and what should be the result?

Comment: try this in a Row: 
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [....]
)

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: Wrap(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('assets/icons/FB.png'),
                  Image.asset('assets/icons/INSTA.png'),
                  Image.asset('assets/icons/YT.png'),
                  Image.asset('assets/icons/TWT.png')
                ],
              ),
            )
```

this is the code the images are still in vertical mode